# Obtener total de categorías de "Tabla A" y sumatorias de "Tabla B" SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Tengo 2 tablas, `Categorías` contiene las categorías de un producto y `Registros` contiene los registros de productos, en donde existe un campo de categoría (haciendo referencia al `ID` de `Categorías`), al realizar la query obtengo como resultado el total de registros de `Registros` separado por categoría (`Categorías`), pero al filtrar por algún cliente específico (campo de la tabla `Registros`), solo me muestra los registros de productos y las categorías a las que pertenecen, pero necesito que se muestre en todos los casos las 5 categorías.

EJEMPLO:

### Total

```
Cotizacion   6  
CotizacionE  3  
Iniciativa   6  
Licitacion   12     
Propuesta    591
```

---

### Con filtro por Cliente

```
Cotizacion  1   
Propuesta   1
```

---

## Resultado que necesito:

```
Cotizacion   1  
CotizacionE  0 o (null)     
Iniciativa   0 o (null)     
Licitacion   0 o (null)     
Propuesta    1
```

## Query:

```
SELECT dbo.lead_categorias.nombre, 
       COUNT(dbo.lead.id) as Cantidad, 
       sum(dbo.lead.valor_estimado) as GeneracionTotal 
FROM dbo.lead 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.lead_categorias 
           ON dbo.lead_categorias.id = dbo.lead.categoria 
WHERE lead.client_id = 11330
GROUP BY dbo.lead_categorias.nombre
```

Comment: puedes postear el código que estás usando?

Comment: @Lamak listo, actualizado

Comment: que base de datos estas utilizando

Comment: @JackNavaRow SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo, debes hacer el `LEFT JOIN` usando `lead_categorias` como la primera tabla. Después de eso tienes 2 alternativas, hacer el join con una subquery o agregar el filtro de cliente en la condición del join.

Opción 1:

```
SELECT  lc.nombre, 
        COUNT(l.id) Cantidad, 
        SUM(l.valor_estimado) GeneracionTotal 
FROM dbo.lead_categorias lc
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM dbo.lead
            WHERE client_id = 11330) l
    ON lc.id = l.categoria 
GROUP BY lc.nombre;
```

Opción 2:

```
SELECT  lc.nombre, 
        COUNT(l.id) Cantidad, 
        SUM(l.valor_estimado) GeneracionTotal 
FROM dbo.lead_categorias lc
LEFT JOIN dbo.lead l
    ON lc.id = l.categoria 
    AND client_id = 11330
GROUP BY lc.nombre;
```

Ambas consultas te entregarán el mismo resultado (y usarán el mismo plan de ejecución). Normalmente yo uso la opción 1, porque deja de manera más evidente la forma en la que estoy filtrando los datos.

Como comentario, te recomiendo que te acostumbres a usar alias en las tablas en vez del nombre completo.

Comment: muchas gracias! funciono! y últimamente he usado alias, solo que para este ejemplo no lo aplique.

Comment: Ésto podría traducirse en : "Usa RIGTH OUTER JOIN en lugar del Left" ?

Comment: @FederHico `RIGHT JOIN` es una abominación que debe morir (es broma....pero jamás usaré un `RIGHT JOIN` en mi vida). Y de todas formas, lo importante era la forma de hacer el filtro. Si el op lo usaba en el `WHERE`, no obtendría los resultados que quiere

Comment: @Lamak ¿porqué debe morir right join??? Sin ánimo de crear un debate aquí. Tanto left join como right join están basados en teoria de consjuntos. La única explicación que encuentro es que son equivalentes y por lo tanto prescindibles.

Comment: @RaulLuna quizás no leíste la parte del comentario que dice que es broma?

Comment: @Lamak Ya, lo leí, pero lo entendí como que "right join está desaconsejado". Ok, perdón por el malentendido.